# protractor bootstrap validation pop message

Tags: javascript, html, protractor, ui-automation

I want to do the validation using protractor for bootstrap pop up.  I used the below code it ran successfully three times but now its getting null.

```
element.all(by.css("input:required")).first().getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
    expect(text.should.be.equal("Please fill out this field."));
})
```

The pop up is similar to this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1209

Comment: @Bill  any update on it.