# protractor bootstrap validation pop message html5

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, protractor

I want to do the validation using protractor for bootstrap pop up. I used the below code it ran successfully three times but now its getting null.
Var content = element.all(by.css(.'username'));
Console.log(content):;

For your reference relates to below:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674254/protractor-bootstrap-validation-pop-message#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674254/protractor-bootstrap-validation-pop-message#_=_)

Comment: Have you checked quoting the parameter `var content = element.all(by.css('.username')); ` ?

Comment: Yeah it's not the problem .how do I locate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674254/protractor-bootstrap-validation-pop-message#_=_

Comment: It looks like you need to wait for it to be present, then start interrogating it. Have you tried waiting with expected conditions?

Comment: Yes I have tried wait but how to locate the pop up element as   it's coming from bootstrap library

Comment: oh, perhaps you need to wait for the window handle count to be a certain number (one more than before) and then switch to the popup  (using its title to find the right window, say; or noting the handle of the current window before popup, then choosing the one that is not that) and then work on it. waitForWindowCount at https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper may be helpful with that.

Comment: Even this library can't help in html5 pop up validation as it's very difficult to get text from pop up as it's not diaplayed in HTML when we do inspect.

Comment: ok, I'm out of ideas, sorry. except maybe https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1554

Comment: This is the similar issue but no solution for it.https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1209